# Matrix diagonal indexing in multiple dimensions with interpolation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a 3d-matrix

```
V(a,b,c)
```

where a, b, and c are lengths of vectors A, B, and C. 
There is a vector X of length x that **jointly** determines values for the first and second dimension of V. The values A(X) and B(X) do not have to be on the grid defined by A or B. So, for a given X,  I want to choose the element

```
V(A(X), B(X), :)
```

where A(X) and B(x) are within the bounds defined by the vectors A, and B, but not necessarily grid points. I am interpolating over the values in V as follows:

```
[Ag, Bg, Cg] = ndgrid(A,B,C);
V_q = griddedInterpolant(Ag,Bg,Cg,V,'linear');
```

What I would like to do is address the function V at the diagonal elements in the first two dimensions only. This is because X determines these two dimensions at the same time. I first define the function V over the new values and then evaluate the function at each point:

```
[aq, bq, cq] = ndgrid(A(X),B(X),C); % new grids
Vq = V_q(aq,bq,cq);
```

The elements I am looking for are given by

```
diags = Vq(bsxfun(@plus,[1:x+1:x*x]',[0:c-1]*x*x));
```

It seems inefficient to me to first evaluate the V matrix at all points defined by the AxB space, not just the diagonal. I was hoping there is a way to write this using the cellfun command, but unfortunately I do not know how.

I am attaching an example:

```
A = 1:2; a = length(A); 
B = 1:3; b = length(B); 
C = 1:4; c = length(C);
V = reshape(1:a*b*c,[a,b,c]);
[ag, bg, cg] = ndgrid(A,B,C);
V_q = griddedInterpolant(ag,bg,cg,V,'linear');

x = 5;
Ax = linspace(A(1),A(end),x);
Bx = linspace(B(1),B(end),x);

[aq, bq, cq] = ndgrid(Ax,Bx,C); % new grids
Vq = V_q(aq,bq,cq);

% Solution:
diags = Vq(bsxfun(@plus,(1:x+1:x*x)',(0:c-1)*x*x))
diags =

1.0000    7.0000   13.0000   19.0000
2.2500    8.2500   14.2500   20.2500
3.5000    9.5000   15.5000   21.5000
4.7500   10.7500   16.7500   22.7500
6.0000   12.0000   18.0000   24.0000
```